# both USB ports randomly stop working

Tags: linux, usb, kernel-modules, shutdown

the problem usually occurs about once per day, seemingly at random, but occasionally two times, and occasionally zero times.

devices connected are: a new STAR printer with it's own power supply, connected using a parallel to USB cable, and a low cost wired barcode scanner.

ever since this problem began, i have added the follow kernel parameters to `/etc/default/grub` though the problem continues:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet usbcore.autosuspend=-1 acpi=force apm=power_off irqpoll"
```

the computer in use is a thinkpad X200 running latest debian. hibernate and suspend are disabled on an OS level. i have tried changing the two USB related options in the BIOS but they don't seem to make a difference.

when the error occurs, the computer will not shutdown properly, and hangs on a blinking cursor on a blank screen. the computer shuts down completely normally if it is shutdown before the error occurs.

i have not tested a copy of the OS on other hardware, or the computer with a different OS.

note that the failing USB ports are a bigger issue for me than the failing shutdown.

the USB devices continue working as normal after a reboot, which suggests a software based problem to me, and hopefully an easy fix.

**update**: the error last occurred at 11:53 and 150 lines of the `/var/log/messages` file can be found here: http://pastebin.com/P1KYGRqp

Comment: what devices are on the usb ports? are they using more than 500mA on each port?

Comment: a STAR printer which has it's own kettle power supply and a wired barcode scanner. according to the ebay page the barcode scanner is:
110mA working current, 40mA static current

Comment: when the ports hang you might try [this](http://www.zedt.eu/tech/linux/restarting-usb-subsystem-centos/) to restart them.  Also, hardware-wise again, ensure the usb cables are less than 5metres long, or even less if using passive extension cables.

Comment: the link you posted worked ! though it was under `uhci_hcd`. i had previously tried using `modprobe -r`, but it simply said they were in use. also, i had assumed the barcode scanner wasn't the problem, since both USB ports locked up. many thanks, feel free to post as answer if you want a vote

Comment: it is just a workaround: we still dont know why the ports hang. Do you see any useful error messages in `/var/log/messages` or similar file?

Comment: i'll update you next time it happens, made a bash script and keyboard shortcut for now

Comment: oops unfortunately the manual unbind/bind file doesn't actually work. manually disabling the driver's before the error occurs appeared to produce the same kind of problem, when i tried yesterday. but actually, when the actual error happened today, sending device names to bind/unbind actually just hangs. i have a `tail` of `messages` if you'd like to see, but honestly i don't know how to interpret it.

Comment: if you are still curious - and don't worry if you're not - here's 150 lines of the /var/log/messages file of exactly when the error occured. i am confident it occurred at 11:53, as a transaction was saved to a database at 11:56, with the first item having been scanned http://pastebin.com/P1KYGRqp

Comment: Yes, the `USB disconnect` in your log seems clear, but I dont have any help to offer. I have had usb devices that reset randomly, but they dont usually hang the driver. You might try adding an external hub to perhaps isolate some weird incompatibility.